# Prevent Route Creation When Bringing Up Network Interface

Tags: networking

I'm working on creating some VM's that will be accessible to the outside world. The server I'm using has 4 NIC cards. I would like one NIC card on a private network that acts as management interface for the host OS (em4). I would like another one or two NIC cards acting as interface for my bridge device (em1 slaved to br0). Traffic should not be routed from the bridge to the host OS or vice versa ever! I'm not sure if I've achieved full isolation by using the bridge method, and I'm open to suggestions for that as well.

If I just have my host NIC card up, my routing table looks as follows.
Please note that IP addresses have been altered for security reasons.

```
[root@someserv ~]# ip route
default via 10.110.0.1 dev em4 proto dhcp metric 101 
10.110.0.0/21 dev em4 proto kernel scope link src 10.110.0.235 metric 101
```

Communication works perfectly here. The problem starts when I bring up my bridge device. I have set the nmcli option 'ipv4.never-default', so a default route is never added for the bridge interface, but after bringing up br0, either using DHCP or manual assignment, I get the following in my routing table.

```
[root@someserv ~]# ip route
default via 10.110.0.1 dev em4 proto dhcp metric 101
10.110.0.0/21 dev em4 proto kernel scop link src 10.110.0.235 metric 101
167.91.112.0/21 dev br0 proto kernel scrop link src 167.91.112.50 metric 425
```

That last entry is a problem because my work computer lies on the same network as 167.91.112.0. The route goes nowhere, and it prevents me from managing my server, so every time I bring up the bridge, I need to go and delete this route. This is very annoying since I need to be connected to an actual terminal vs SSH.

Does anyone know a way to prevent the interface from adding this route? Or, is there a better way to setup my interface for my VM's. I've seen this question asked before here ([Can I prevent a default route being added when bringing up an interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182967/can-i-prevent-a-default-route-being-added-when-bringing-up-an-interface)), but the answer is old and certainly not relevant to Oracle Linux 7 or 8.

Finally, one other idea I tried was to just create an empty route file.

```
[root@someserv ~]# cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
[root@someserv network-scripts]# ls -l *route*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  870 May 22  2020 ifdown-routes
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2001 May 22  2020 ifup-routes
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Aug 22 15:02 route-br0
```

That doesn't work either.

~ Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I cannot speak for the sanity of your network configuration, so I will focus on a workaround.** What solves your issue is deleting the route after bringing up br0, right? My guess is that your interfaces are NetworkManager controlled. So my proposition is to let NetworkManager delete your route every time your `br0` interface goes up.

You would need to create a bash script inside `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` . This bash script would basically do *something* like

```
ip route del 167.91.112.0/21 dev br0
```

There are lots of examples on NetworkManager scripts. I hope this helps you solve your issue, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Alex.

You're absolutely right. That fix works for both DHCP and manual configuration. The command 'man 8 networkmanager' is very helpful. In my case I just create a script called 99-bridge-up in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d.

```
[root@someserv dispatcher.d]# cat 99-bridge-up 
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "br0" ] && [ "$2" == "up" ]; then
    ip route del 167.91.112.0/21
fi
```